# JS not working. Referenced right, but not working

Tags: javascript, html

http://mogswamp.com/testing/

Clicking the "Click to see incentives" header should make the boxes drop down.  I have no idea what is wrong.  I've been fiddling with this a while, and am at a loss.  I'd really appreciate some help.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/testing/extend.js"></script>
```

extend.js

```
(function(){
  $('.incentives').hide();

  $('.incentives-click').on("click", function(){
    $('.incentives').fadeToggle();
  });
})();
```

If you need me to submit anything else, just ask, but it should be easy to see in the page source.  Thanks.

Comment: Just trouble-shooting here, but could you please wrap your code instead of what it is now, in `$(function(){`?

Comment: the $ did it -.-  Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is executing before your scripts and/or page is fully loaded. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.incentives').hide();

  $('.incentives-click').on("click", function(){
    $('.incentives').fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either put your javascript at the bottom of the page *as you should*, rather at the `head`, or make it work with content added after it. Try **[event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**, or waiting for [**DOM ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)